# Laravel access forbidden css/js

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5 project. And a WAMP server.

The 'index.php' page is correctly displayed, but not the css and js files. Each time I have this kind of error:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /ecole/public/css/bootstrap.min.css on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

But I think that the problem is not this file. I think that the pb is about the apache configuration (the httpd.conf) , but I do not know what exactly.

Comment: Did you use the [`asset()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset) function?

Comment: I do like that :  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Did you check the files permissions?

Comment: Found the problem. The css/js ... files were crypted. They appear in "green". I solved that and now all is fine. Thanks Mina Abadir.